# How can I get QGIS Plugins to work through the proxy internet settings?

Tags: qgis, network, plugins, proxy

For QGIS on my work computer, I add in the appropriate information under Settings - Network - Proxy.  This allows me to access plugin repositories, but sometimes plugins do not work.  I would get 'network failure' or proxy restrictions.

How do QGIS plugins that require internet access work if the Proxy/network settings fail?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting up the proxy under the Network settings, you may need to add an exception.  For example, to properly use the QGISCloud plugin, you need to open your Computer's Internet Settings, Connections, LAN Settings, and and *qgiscloud* as an exception.  This will allow your plugin to access the internet properly.